# Does the Corona SDK support iOS app subscriptions?

Tags: ios, coronasdk

I see they support in-app purchases, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never even heard of this before (incidentally, thanks for bringing it to my attention) and I've been frequently visiting their website as I work on my current project, so I would say that no they don't support subscriptions. This must be a brand new revenue model Apple just unveiled, so there hasn't been time for this to find it's way into Corona.

Comment: I did hear someone on IRC say that they thought subscriptions functioned just like any other in-app purchase, but I haven't been able to confirm that.